# CSS making <select> single row buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am writing a to-do list but cannot figure out the css to turn my  tag into 3 separate side-by-side buttons. This is my current code:

```
            <select onChange={this.handleChange} name="date" id="date-select" size="4">
                <option value="today">Today</option>
                <option value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
                <option value="week">This week</option>
            </select>
            <button className="td-add" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>+</button>
```

My  is the big square on the right containing (today, tomorrow, this week). I would like to make the height fit in 1 row so it looks in-line with the input bar, and if possible, make the options appear like clickable buttons.

[image]

Comment: Take out the size attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your question has been answered here:
[How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

tl:dr, option element styling is limited

An alternative would be to rewrite the three option elements as three buttons if you want them to sit side by side.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Hyetigran said, option element styling is limited.

I suggest you use three checkboxes, styled to be buttons and then have javascript that unticks the others when one becomes ticked.